# Login to webpage not working with Python requests module

Tags: python, html, authentication, python-requests

I am trying to use the Python requests module to authenticate to a website and then retrieve some information from it. This is the login part of the page:

```
<div>

    <label class="label-left" for="username"> … </label>
    <input id="username" class="inputbox" type="text" size="18" alt="username" name="username"></input>

</div>
<div>

    <label class="label-left" for="passwd"> … </label>
    <input id="passwd" class="inputbox" type="password" alt="password" size="18" name="passwd"></input>

</div>
<div> … </div>
<div class="readon">

    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Login" name="Submit"></input>
```

What I am doing now is:

```
payload = {
    'username': username,
    'passwd': password,
    'Submit':'Login'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post(login, data=payload)
    ans = s.get(url)
    print ans.text
```

The problem is that I get the same login page, even after the authentication. The response code is 200, so everything should be ok. Am I missing something?

---

UPDATE

Thanks to the comment, I have analyzed the post requests and I've seen that there are some hidden parameters. Among them, there are some parameters whose values vary between different requests. For this reason, I am simply getting them with BeautifulSoup and then updating the payload of the post request as follows:

```
with requests.Session() as s:

    login_page = s.get(login)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(login_page.text)
    inputs = soup.findAll(name='input',type='hidden')

    for el in inputs:
        name = el['name']
        value = el['value']
        payload[name]=value

    s.post(login, data=payload)
    ans = s.get(url)
```

Nevertheless, I am still getting the login page. There can be some other influencing elements?

Comment: Is there no hidden input?

Comment: Did you try to manually log in and analyze request params in your browser?

Comment: I've updated the question according to your comments

Comment: Could you provide the link to that page?

Comment: I cannot provide the link to the page, but I have discovered that the problem is that requests does not obtain the cookies from the website. If I write myself the cookies and pass it into the post and get requests, then it works. This still puzzles me

Comment: I have resolved the problem. The issue was that the site had a button for accepting cookies that needed to be pressed. I solved the problem by using mechanize, because requests was still having some issues